# How find rows and columns in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, find

I have variable matrix :

```
A = [1     2     8     8     1
     4     6     8     1     1
     5     3     1     1     8];
```

and I have variable B :

```
B=[2 3 1 8 8];
```

Question is how to find rows and columns (sort by rows) in variable A from variable B.

Example, first index in variable B is 2, and then I want to find value 2 in variable A and get to first rows and columns, and next process until index 5, but if rows and columns has been used so get second position (ex. index 4 & 5 having same value).

```
rows;
columns;
```

Result is:

```
rows = 1 3 1 1 1
columns = 2 2 1 3 4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use can use find and sub2ind to achieve what you want 
but for that you have to take transpose of your A first

```
 A = [1     2     8     8     1
     4     6     8     1     1
     5     3     1     1     8];
B= [2 3 1 8 8];
TMP = A.';
for i = 1:length(B)
   indx = find(TMP== B(i),1,'first')   %Finding the element of B present in A 
   if(~isempty(indx )) % If B(i)  is a member of A 
       [column(i),row(i)] = ind2sub(size(TMP),indx) % store it in row and column matrix
       TMP(indx) = nan; % remove that element
   end
end
```

> > column =
> >
> > ```
> > 2     2     1     3     4
> > ```
> >
> > row =
> >
> > ```
> > 1     3     1     1     1
> > ```

As in one of the comments Usama suggested preallocation of memory
you can do that by using

```
row = zeros(1,sum(ismember(B,A)))
column= zeros(1,sum(ismember(B,A)))
```

The above code works even if there are some members of B not present in A

Comment: A drawback with this solution is that you change the matrix A.

Comment: You can store it in some Temp matrix

Comment: I don't know if it's useful for OP but if one value of B is bigger than the max value of A your code will crash

Comment: @obchardon no it wont !

Comment: @Umar now it wont

Comment: Consider pre-allocating the memory for `row` and `column` as it is not considered a good-programming practice to grow a vector size in a loop. For reference, read this: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/preallocating-arrays.html

Answer (score 0):

Use `find`. The function could return both a linear index or a row/col index.

Using linear index a solution could be

```
idx = zeros(size(B));
for i = 1:numel(B)
    % Find all indexes
    tmpIdx = find(A == B(i));
    % Remove those already used
    tmpIdx = setdiff(tmpIdx, idx);
    % Get the first new unique
    idx(i) = tmpIdx(1);
end
% Convert index to row and col
[rows, cols] = ind2sub(size(A),idx)
```

Giving:

```
rows =  1 3 1 1 2
cols =  2 2 1 3 3
```

Note that as the linear indexing goes down column by column, the result here differs from the one in your example (although still a correct index)

```
rows = 1 3 1 1 1
columns= 2 2 1 3 4
```

But to get this you could just transpose the A matrix (`A.'`) and flip the rows and cols (the result from `ind2sub`)

Comment: @Sardar_Usama Ah, yes, correct. But for non-complex matrix/array they are the same right? Or is it another difference that I'm not aware of?

Comment: This is because the conjugate of a real number is the same number! So, you may say that the functionality is same but  if you are stating that `A'` is a transpose then this statement is incorrect although!

Answer (score 0):

Here is on solution where I use for loop, I tried to optimize the number of iteration and the computational cost. If there is no corresponding value between B and A the row/col index return NaN.

```
[Bu,~,ord] = unique(B,'stable');

% Index of each different values
[col,row] = arrayfun(@(x) find(A'==x),Bu,'UniformOutput',0)

% For each value in vector B we search the first "non already used" corresponding value in A.
for i = 1:length(B)
    if ~isempty(row{ord(i)})
        r(i) = row{ord(i)}(1);
        row{ord(i)}(1) = [];
        c(i) = col{ord(i)}(1);
        col{ord(i)}(1) = [];
    else
        r(i) = NaN;
        c(i) = NaN;
    end
end
```

**RESULT:**

```
c = [2   2   1   3   4]

r = [1   3   1   1   1]
```

Comment: Consider pre-allocating the memory for `r` and `c` as it is not considered a good-programming practice to grow a vector size in a loop. For reference, read this: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/preallocating-arrays.html Your solution seems to work although :-)

Comment: @Sardar_Usama impossible to pre-allocate `col` and `row` since the Output is not uniform. But yeah it's possible to create `c = zeros(length(B),1);`